# Python - Table not found error when using SQlite3 with Daemonize

Tags: python, sqlite, python-daemon

I have a slack bot that accesses an SQlite database. When I run the bot in the foreground, everything works but when I run it as a daemon, it seems to connect to my database but then returns "table not found" on every query that I run.

The thing is, this used to work until my latest version and I can't find what changed, so I made a stripped down version as a test but I still have the same problem. See below:

```
import syslog
import sqlite3
import os
from daemonize import Daemonize
from slackclient import SlackClient
from qatoken import token

#Slack vars
nickname = "NetBot-QA"
dump = "#net-dump-qa"
channel = "#net-alerts-qa"
avatar = ":loader:"

#Daemonize vars
pid = "/tmp/netbot-qa.pid"
app = "net-bot-qa"
syslog.openlog('netbot', 0, syslog.LOG_LOCAL4 )

###################################################### MAIN
def main():

    sc = SlackClient(token)
    sc.api_call("chat.postMessage", username=nickname, channel=dump, text="{0}/net-alerts-test.db".format(os.path.dirname(__file__)), icon_emoji=avatar)

    try:
        conn = sqlite3.connect("{0}/net-alerts-test.db".format(os.path.dirname(__file__)))
        c = conn.cursor()
        c.execute("SELECT * from maint_calendar")
        sc.api_call("chat.postMessage", username=nickname, channel=dump, text="made it!", icon_emoji=avatar)
    except (SystemExit, KeyboardInterrupt):
        raise
    except Exception, e:
        sc.api_call("chat.postMessage", username=nickname, channel=dump, text="The bot crashed", icon_emoji=avatar)
        syslog.syslog("error: {0}".format(e))

########################################################################################
#main()
########################################################################################
#main()
daemon = Daemonize(app=app, pid=pid, action=main)
daemon.start()
```

If I run main(), I get the slack message "Made it!", but if I comment it out and run daemon.start() instead, I get "The bot crashed".

When I cat /var/log/messages, this is what I see:

```
Nov 16 09:47:37 server1 netbot: error: no such table: maint_calendar

[root@server1 net-alerts]# pwd
/opt/bots/net-alerts

[root@server1 net-alerts]# sqlite3 net-alerts-test.db
SQLite version 3.7.17 2013-05-20 00:56:22
sqlite> .schema
CREATE TABLE maint_calendar (start time, finish time, summary text, dc_tag text, provider text, CONSTRAINT start_sum PRIMARY KEY (start, summary));
```

I've also tried running this with a static path to the db but os.path.dirname has worked very well with every other script I use. I found another post saying you have to make the DB connection inside the Daemon context (main()) but I've been doing this from the start. I'm running out of ideas.

Comment: Try to put ; at the end of your SQL statement first, please :)

Comment: Please print this into your log: os.path.dirname( \_\_file__ ), so you can see if it's really the same path even if it's daemonized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me, that this line:

```
conn = sqlite3.connect("{0}/net-alerts-test.db".format(os.path.dirname(__file__)))
```

Is actually connecting to two different sources, depending if you daemonize or just run main().

Just save the file to db in a global variable, which you use later. E.g.:

```
DB_PATH = "{0}/net-alerts-test.db".format(os.path.dirname(__file__))
...
def main():

    sc = SlackClient(token)
    sc.api_call("chat.postMessage", username=nickname, channel=dump, text="{0}/net-alerts-test.db".format(os.path.dirname(__file__)), icon_emoji=avatar)

    try:
        conn = sqlite3.connect(DB_PATH)
```

Comment: Didn't work. I copied your code but I get the same error. That first slack message displays the path from the point of view of main() and it shows the correct path in both cases. I had also tried with a static path and it didn't solve the issue.

Comment: Also when debugging you should leave the exception to raise, so you see the full stack error: except Exception, e:
        sc.api_call("chat.postMessage", username=nickname, channel=dump, text="The bot crashed", icon_emoji=avatar)
        syslog.syslog("error: {0}".format(e)) raise e

Comment: Would I see that error in Stderr? Since this is running as a daemon I have to send the output to syslog but even with raise e at the end, I'm not seeing any more information.

Comment: Yes, you will not see it, unless you redirect stderr to a file to see the traceback for whole error.

Comment: Alright, I got rid of os.path.dirname entirely and now it's working. I'm not sure what to think because I even rolled back to my earlier version where I AM using os.path.dirname, and I brought my old DB from backups, and the bot was still crashing at the same place. So the lesson here is: Be mindful of os paths when using Daemonize. You were right, have my upvote.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I have hard-coded the full path of the DB file and its working nice!

**Example:**

```
dbconn = sqlite3.connect("/home/pi/db.db")
cur = dbconn.cursor()
cur.execute("INSERT INTO raw_data(id, packet, db_insert_time, sync) VALUES(NULL, ?, ?, ?)", ('Line', x, 'N'))

dbconn.commit()
print('DB Insert success!')
```